# Mitosearch Data Entry

Tags: dna, familytreedna.com, mitochondrial-dna, mitosearch.org

I'm entering my uncle's mtDNA results from FamilyTreeDNA into [mitosearch](http://www.mitosearch.org/). But I ran into two problems that their help doesn't seem to answer.

[image]

Problem 1: FamilyTreeDNA provides differences from two different reference sequences: RSRS (the Reconstructed Sapiens Reference System) and rCRS (the revised Cambridge Reference System).  Which one do I enter into Mitosearch?

Problem 2: See the dropdown in the above image. It allows entry of the four nucleotides A, C, G and T. My uncle's mutations include some heteroplasmy, which is the presence of more than one mtDNA sequence in a cell. They are represented by different letters. In my uncle's case, one of his mutations has a Y, which I understand to represent C or T. How do I enter this into Mitosearch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found in the Family Tree DNA Learning Centre, [an article on the mtDNA Matches Page](https://www.familytreedna.com/learn/user-guide/mtdna-myftdna/mt-matches-page/), and they have in their Q&A there this question and answer:

[image]

When I try this procedure, it loads my HVR1 and HVR2 results into Mitosearch for me.

Answer for Problem 1: It uses the rCRS values

Answer for Problem 2: For the mutations that are not one of A, C, G or T, it simply leaves that column blank.

It's still not perfectly clear, though, because the Y mutation got entered as 1670Y and gave an error. I changed it to 16270 and it still wasn't accepted:

[image]

So I entered a "T" where it should be a Y. That was accepted, and I added a note stating that the "T" should be a Y, meaning "C" or "T".